# Chromedriver text file busy

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have an app that runs selenium and does some testing. when I run my code in stand-alone, it works perfectly. But when I run it several times, to test multiple things in the same time, I get an error.

Here is my code :

```
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
    chrome_options.add_argument("window-size=1920,1080")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-features=NetworkService")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=chrome_options)
    driver.get(URL)
```

and here's the error

```
    files = self.__unpack(file_path)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/webdriver_manager/driver_cache.py", line 99, in __unpack
    return extract_zip(path, to_directory)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/webdriver_manager/archive.py", line 7, in extract_zip
    archive.extractall(to_directory)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.6/zipfile.py", line 1524, in extractall
    self._extract_member(zipinfo, path, pwd)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.6/zipfile.py", line 1578, in _extract_member
    open(targetpath, "wb") as target:
    OSError: [Errno 26] Text file busy: '/home/root/.wdm/drivers/chromedriver/80.0.3987.106/linux64/chromedriver'
```

my understanding is that there is an instance of chromedriver which is already running, which is possible as I can run this code in the background. How can I handle this error?

Comment: Did you find a fix for it?

Comment: @Newskooler not really,  I switched to pypputeer which is faster and gave me less headache

Comment: I did know of this one. Thanks, I will check it out.

Answer (score 4):

I believe you are right: the error happens when there is already an instance of chrome running.

To fix first find the processes running `chrome`. You can do this by search processes which contain the name `chrome` like so:

```
pidof chrome
```

Then you can kill all of them like so:

```
pkill -f chrome
```

Re-running your code afterwards should not produce this error.

Comment: this does not fix the problem as you have to do this all the time (the problem occurs often, and I do this manually...)

Comment: If the above fixed the problem, it means that you are creating processes which are left running. So this is a starting point to investigate where you create these processes and then to handle the code such that they are closed properly in order to not have this error the next time you star your code.

Comment: +1 I agree. I tried multiple approach but couldn't really predict the way selenium will behave... all my connections were supposed to close properly... anyways thanks for the heads up.

Comment: In case the chromedriver is the issue you can try `pkill -f chromedriver`

Answer (score 0):

I meet this error recently, I tried "rsync" to copy the chromedriver to a new directory, then update the environment variable to the new path, and it works.